# Reading from .csv file

Tags: c++

I am trying to save variables in .csv file, even after closing the program and then when opening again to read them from the .csv so, the variables won't reset after closing. The `$balance` works fine, but `$level` and `$cases`'s values are 1 every time. They are saved in the .csv, but I can't read them.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int $balance = 0, $new_balance, $bet_amount, $random_number, $multiplies, $number_type_number, case_opening;
  int $level = 1, $cases = 1, $xp = 0;
  int $input_balance = 0, $input_level = 1, $input_cases = 1;
  string $free_coins, $bet_type, $number_type_color, $number_type_odd_even, $number_type_row, $bet_type_color;
  string $bet_type_halves, $bet_type_third, $bet_type_row;
  string $roll_again;
  ofstream myFile;
  ifstream inputFile;
  string line, line1, line2;

  /*Useless Code*/

  inputFile.open("database.txt");

  while (getline(inputFile, line)) {
    istringstream ss(line);
    ss >> $input_balance;
    $balance = $input_balance;  
  }

  while (getline(inputFile, line1)) {
    istringstream ss1(line1);
    ss1 >> $input_level;
    $level = $input_level;
  }

  while (getline(inputFile, line2)) {
    istringstream ss2(line2);
    ss2 >> $input_cases;
    $cases = $input_cases;
  }
    
  do {
   /*More Useless Code*/
   myFile.open("database.txt");
   myFile << $balance << "\t" << $level << "\t" << $cases;
   myFile.close();
  } while($roll_again == "yes" || $roll_again == "y" || $roll_again == "Yes" || $roll_again == "Y");
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mre] with the input file, expected output and actual output. Why all the dollars in the variable names?

Comment: last output before closing the program:
`$balance = 500$ (for example)
 $level = 5
 $cases = 3`
output after opening the program again:
`$balance = 500$
 $level = 1
 $cases = 1`
I need level and cases to be 5 and 3 in this case, but they are 1 every time. $balance is the only one that saves itself.

Comment: This does not seem as a CSV file. CSV means "Comma-separated values". I think not further explanation is needed.

Comment: @F4QU By the way the C++ convention does not add the character `$` before all the variables. I suppose your habit comes from Bash, but adding `$` before all variable names is not good in C++.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't check to see if the `open()` calls are successful.
2. You don't close `inputFile` before writing to `myFile`. How do you know that writes to the file will work when it is already open for reading?
3. Why are you using `while (getline(inputFile, line))`. That doesn't make sense.
   The value of every line will get assigned to `$balance`.
4. You are writing tabs (`"\t"`) to the file instead of newlines (`"\n"`) so all three values will be on one line.
5. Your final loop will never exit if $roll_again is y,Y,yes or Yes. But you never assign a value to $roll_again anyway so why the loop?

Comment: I think you mean "all the line". "every line" makes no sense as the file has only 1 line.

Comment: Probably the variable is assigned in the "`/*More Useless Code*/`" section.